# Sending data to view laravel 8

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-8

**1. Controller**

```
public function show(Questionnare $questionnare)
{
 return view('Questionnaire.show',compact('questionnare'));
}
```

**2. View**

```
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header">{{questionnare->title}}</div>
<div>
```

**3. MYSQL Database**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUUqa.jpg)

**QUESTION**
My Question is Can we show title without using foreach loop ?? because wheneveri try it fails
with Error

> Exception Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: You forgot the `$` sign in front of the variable in your view.

Comment: Typo `{{ $questionnare->title }}`

Comment: If that were the actual code, it would throw an undefined constant error. Also there's an attempt to get `title` on the code, and `name` on the error.

Comment: {{ $questionnare->title }} i Forget to add $ in the Question but in my code $  sign is present !!
my page doest display title

Comment: You don't have "name" in the database, I'm guessing you are using "$questionnare->name" somewhere in the view where you meant "$questionnare->title".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Controller**

Instead of Using This

```
public function show(Questionnare $questionnare)
{
 return view('Questionnaire.show',compact('questionnare'));
}
```

Use This

```
public function show($id)
{
  $questionnare = Questionnare::findorFail($id);
  return view('Questionnaire.show',compact('questionnare'));
    }
```

**2. View**

```
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header">{{$questionnare->title}}</div>
<div>
```

and your title will be displayed on the page ☺☺☺